Agora Video Call Hide Outgoing Video
I currently have somebody building an app for me and they just showed me the video call functionality of Agora implemented in the app. This works fine so far, but we have a "problem" with the outgoing video. We would need the possibility to adjust the size of the outgoing video and to be able to hide the outgoing video entirely. The developers have told me that this is not possible, but there already have been various things that were possible to program, but they just didn't want to go the extra mile, even though it's been asked for before starting to program the app.
And is it possible to adjust the colors of the screens Agora provides?
Does anybody know if there is a possibility to achieve that or is that not possible to implement.
Thank you very much in advance
Miriam
I'm sorry, I can't provide you with any details, since I'm not the one who is programming the app. It's just a general question if it can be achieved.
